# R: Shiny, how to use renderTable to replace reactiveTable?

Tags: r

I am trying to load multiple text files (each has a string of characters) into Shiny and I found a very nice tutorial to begin with: 
https://gist.github.com/jcheng5/4050398
The code is shown below:

#### ui.R

`shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("File input test"),
    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("files", "File data", multiple=TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("filetable")
    )
))`

#### server.R

`shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$filetable <- reactiveTable(function() {
        if (is.null(input$files)) {
        # User has not uploaded a file yet
            return(NULL)
        }
    input$files
    })
})`

The issue I have is that the result got a warning: `reactiveTable is deprecated. Please use renderTable instead.` Besides that, the code does work well.

However, after I replaced reactiveTable with renderTable, I got an error message: `Error: no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "function"`

Any idea how to replace `reactiveTable` with `renderTable` correctly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: use `output$filetable <- renderTable( {
    if (is.null(input$files)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    input$files
  })`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works great.